# How to get the module name from pom in java

Tags: java, maven

I have a requirement in which based on module names, I need to do some operations.
How to fetch the modules name from `pom.xml` in a java class. 
My `pom.xml` has like below :

```
<artifactId>test</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>


<modules>
        <module>name1</module>
        <module>name2</module>    
</modules>
```

I saw we can get `artifactId` and version as below from a property file. Here module is a list how to get the modules names from the list. Any help would be appreciated.

```
version=${project.version}
artifactId=${project.artifactId}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could

- Define the names as Maven properties.
- Define a text file in resources which uses these properties.
- Process this resource file with Maven.
- Read from the resource file in your jar/war.

Comment: How do you handle a variable number of modules?"

Comment: @Andrei I don't understand the question. If you add more modules, add more properties and add them in the text file.

Comment: @JFMeier I _hate_ maven for this :( `module.name` why isn't this a thing is beyond me